# Cannot add 'Power BI Service' in Azure Active Directory to use Power BI API's

Tags: c#, azure, powerbi

According to the Microsoft Power BI Developers documentation
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dn877542.aspx. I first need to register an app in Azure Active Directory.

However when I follow the steps in the link above, I see none of the Microsoft Applications for me to add, let alone see the Power BI one.

Obviously there is something missing, do I need to somehow link my Azure account with an Office 365 account or something ?? Please advice!

Answer (score 4):

It looks like I figured out the issue, it is something which I believe 
others may encounter if they have azure accounts and office 356 accounts!

I registered to PowerBI however I suspected my own Azure account is not associated with my PowerBI Account even though it's the same Email Address.

Seems I was right, when I logged out of my Azure account and then loggeg into PowerBI, when I navigated to portal.azure.com - I ended up in a very different azure account where I was able to then create a new App and add Power BI Service.

Comment: Possibly one azure account was associated with your windows account/live id and the other was associated with your organization id, though the email addresses may have been the same

Comment: Any idea on how to fix it? Maybe there is a way to join the two accounts sharing the same email address? ...

Comment: In my experience you need to use what Microsoft describes as an `organizational account` rather than an `individual account`. I have found that you cannot use the Power BI Pro trial with an `individual account`, Why Microsoft allows two different accounts to use the same email address is beyond my understanding.